Evee Pixelated shadow problem 4.2
Im currently having trouble with my shadows in my scene. I have a sun light that is angled and casting the shadows within the scene. whatever settings I tweak with, the pixilation sill is present and only from the sun light. I opened the project within Blender before 4.0 and didn't seem to have the issue. Ive tried to find the cascading shadow map as a fix and cant find it within 4.2. (also I cant open the file before teh 4.0 releases because my project now crashes) any help?
I've attached the blend file and cleaned up the scene as much as possible. In doing so, the problem has lessened, but it seems to still be present. any help would be amazing! thank you so much !


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

I've just attached it, hopefully it works! thank you so much
